# Create a file on remote server with nodejs

Tags: node.js

What is the easiest way to create a file on a remote server (can be accessed with ssh) in NodeJS?

Example: I work on my local computer, and there exists a remote server with ip 192.168.1.100. I would like to create an empty text file on this server, in path "/home/users/share".

I tried using some **scp** library in NodeJS, but could not copy my file to the remoted server.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean?

If file is created in path, that ssh has access, and rights are set OK, then file be acceseable.

Do you want to generate data on the server and save it? 
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

Choose a file from the disk and upload it to the server? eg: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_uploadfiles.asp

Comment: I am trying to create a new file on a remote server.
For example, if I have a server 192.168.1.100 on my network, and it contains a folder "/home/user/share" - I would like to add a file "test.txt" to this folder.

Comment: @NadavMiran I gave you a solution. You did not understand the question. I mean, how you want to create this file: how to get the data for it.

Comment: My purpose is just creating a file and adding a string to it. The content is not my main issue. Thanks, I'll try finding out the solution in the given links.

Comment: Did you check links what I provided? First link: `fs.writeFile`. Also: `fs.createWriteStream`, `fs.write`, `fs.writeFileSync`, `fs.writeSync`

Comment: I checked the links, but did not find a solution for creating my file on the remote server. It is easy to save a new file on the local file system, but in order to save the file in a remote file system, it seems to be more difficult.

Comment: That is why it is so important to clearly formulate questions. First, you must have the method of manually creating such a file, and then code it in node. One of the options you have in the second answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, you want to create file on different server using Nodejs and want to access the file using `ssh`.

If your server has linux then you can use `rsync` command from terminal.
E.g `rsync --chmod=u+rwx,g+rwx,o+rwx /path/to/file server:/path/to/file`.

And if you want it done from Nodejs then you can use `child_process` library to execute all terminal commands.

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('rsync --chmod=u+rwx,g+rwx,o+rwx /path/to/file server:/path/to/file', (err, () =>
    if (err) {
         // node couldn't execute the command
        return;
     }

}));
```